# Hi, I am using Express with MongoDb, Whenever I make a post request, it shows that message (model made using mongoose) is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Whenever I make a post request, it shows that message is not a constructor.  Here message is a model that I made using mongoose.
And I am exporting this model through
module.exports = message and using this exported model in form_post.js file

**my app.js file**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const port = 3000;
const form_display = require('./routes/form_display');
const form_post = require('./routes/form_post');

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(express.json())

//Backend Connection 
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/sudeepkart", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });
  var db = mongoose.connection;
  db.once("open", function () {
    console.log("We are Connected !!");
  });

// Pug Specific
app.set('view engine', 'pug') //Setting View Engine as Pug 
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')) //Setting views directory so that pug files can be fetched from he views directory

// Express Specific 
app.use(form_display);
app.use(form_post);

app.use('/static',express.static('static'))
app.use((req, res, next)=>{res.status(404).send('<h2>Error Page Not found</h2>')});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
})
```

**my form_post.js file**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Message = require('../models/message.model')
const port = 3000;

router.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
router.use(express.json())

router.post('/message', function (req, res) {
  
    // Creating New Object
    var newMsg = new Message(req.body);
    newMsg.save(function (err, msg) {
    });
  
    res.send('Your message has been successfully submitted');
  })

module.exports = router;
```

**my models/message.model.js  file**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 
 // New Schema and New Model
  
 var message_schema = new mongoose.Schema({ "id":String, "message":String });
 var message = new mongoose.model("message_model", message_schema); // in other words model is a synonym for collection

 module.exports = message;
```

Comment: add your error message if any to the question. 
and remove unnecessary tags. like  [C++ ] or other in this case

Comment: You could destructure your import: `const {message} = require('../models/message.models')`

Comment: @Pandamora Thanks I got it!

Comment: I had to export like this   module.exports = message; and then destructure my import. Thanks!

Comment: But Do we need to destructure models whenever we are exporting them??  as I didn't destructure other imports

Answer (score 0):

Try destructuring it:

```
const {message} = require('../models/message.models')
```

[MDN Documentation for destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

To answer your comment question, because you're trying to import `Message` while only exporting `message`. On your module.exports, I would reccomend always doing `module.exports = {variable1, function2}` etc, so you can destructure it and you can easily debug any issues (and stop confusion with variables too!)